# Why horizontal bar on my website - mobile version?

Tags: css, horizontal-scrolling

any help will be really appreciated.
My website address is ***peopleinside.it***

if you navigate than reduce the browser window size you will see an horizontal scroll bar. I AM unable to understand what is generating this scroll bar and I want remove it as there are no visible elements outside of the page that need the horizontal bar.

Only here: ***peopleinside.it/su-di-me/film/*** horizontal bar is needed **but not in the home page** if the screen is small but not in the home page and in other pages.

I AM unable to find why horizontal scroll bar are showed in my home if the screen is small.

[screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QfkU.png)

[screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYvXb.png)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why have you disabled the clicking on your website? It's not letting me test it at all!

Comment: Sorry is for protect code and images.

Comment: If they have to steal the code and image, they'll do it anyway just by pressing Ctrl+U. Disabling mouse clicks would do no good to your website I think. Anyways.

Comment: @PeopleInside disabling right click doesn't protect this... pressing command shift c exposes the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
.art-postcontent {
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}
```

should do the trick. Your table isn't responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Is google and this CSS fix the issue:

```html
#google_translate_element span {
  white-space: normal !important;    
}

.pt-cv-colsys {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```